# Create a Folder relative to selected file in windows store app

Tags: windows-store-apps, directory-permissions

I am struggling with the file api of windows store apps. I want to create subfolder while data export to write some additional files into. That means:

```
data.txt
extra
+ 1.txt
+ 2.txt
```

The data.txt is picked by user so it's no problem to write. But how could I create this subfolder?

```
storageFolder.getFolderAsync("C\some\path\where\data\is\extra").done(...
```

does not work. It seems to fail because of the security restrictions.

I could live with the restiction to write into documents. But it also doesn not work when the user selects a data.txt in documents folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that this is "As Designed" behavior.

Yoy can do whatever you want in you application specific folders (AppData)
You can read/edit a file anywhere on the system when a user give you the authorization through file activation or filepicker. There is api to extend lifetime of that authorization
You can read/edit a file Inside knownfolder if your app has required capabilities checked in its manifest.

Other file system interactions will fail due to security restrictions.

Comment: I granted the app to write in documents. I can create folders by using the Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.documentsLibrary. But the access is denied if I use storageFolder.getFolderAsync("C:\\users..\\Documents").

Comment: You should use KnownFolders to access Documents Library : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.documentslibrary.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript#code-snippet-1
In addition you might want to declare file types you want to manipulate in the package manifest in Declarations->File Type Associations

Comment: In addition you must first create your "extra" directory using CreateFolderAsync before trying to perform a getFolderAsync on that directory : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/br227257.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If decided to let the user select a directory instead of a file. [FolderPicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker.folderpicker.aspx) will handle this job. It's not my prefered solution because the user loose the ability to pick a name of the target folder. A create option in FolderPicker like in Windows non-RT would solve it, but no way yet.

So my user have to create a export folder in Documents by Explorer and then pick it in app.

My structure is:

```
Documents
+ export (created by user in explorer)
++ 2012-10-04 (hard coded by app)
+++ data.txt
+++ extra
++++ 1.txt
++++ 2.txt
```